# How to use single navigator instead of several in react native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I need both drawer and stack navigators functionality. I use react-navigation library, because it is the best today. But nested in each other they work too slow. I decided to increase speed by using only one of them. So what would be easier to implement? Now I am working on stack navigator with react-native-gesture-handler's drawer. I faced a problem with rerendering, when I choose a page in drawer whole screen rerenders like we have just moved to another screen and that animation (or how it can be called) should be removed but how?

Will it be easier to use drawer navigation and are there some ways to hide drawer navigation menu's items and the whole drawer on some screens?

If you know another options how to increase perfomance of nested navigators, please write your variant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way here is to use navigation drawer:

```
import React from 'react';

import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './src/screens/ProfileScreen';
import HiddenScreen from './src/screens/HiddenScreen';
import {
  DrawerContentScrollView,
  DrawerItemList,
  createDrawerNavigator,
} from '@react-navigation/drawer';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const CustomDrawerContent = (props) => {
  const { state, ...rest } = props;
  const newState = { ...state}
  newState.routes = newState.routes.filter(item => item.name !== 'Hidden') 

  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
     <DrawerItemList state={newState} {...rest} />
</DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        drawerContent={CustomDrawerContent}
        initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen
          options={{gestureEnabled: false}}
          name="Hidden"
          component={HiddenScreen}
        />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

### **1. Disabling swipe gesture**

```
options={{gestureEnabled: false}}
```

### **2. Hiding menu item**

Custom drawer content should be created and connected to Drawer navigator. Then props should be filtered in order to exclude unnecessary menu items.

```
const { state, ...rest } = props;
  const newState = { ...state}
  newState.routes = newState.routes.filter(item => item.name !== 'Hidden')
```